# Instagram Profile Picture in Full-Resolution?

Tags: instagram

how do I get the profile picture of an instagram profile in full-res? (The old URL scheme stopped working today).

regex='profile_pic_url_hd":"([0-9a-zA-Z._-/:]*)",'

Is working for 320px pictures, but nothing else. The prefix to the 150x150 img is different, but the ID/ending of the url with jpg is the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Okay guys I found a final solution:

1. Get the **user_id** of the account using this link [https://www.instagram.com/{name}/?__a=1](https://www.instagram.com/%7Bname%7D/?__a=1)
2. Visit this JSON-API with the user_id above [https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/{user_id}/info/](https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/%7Buser_id%7D/info/)
   The full size profile picture link can be found in **[hd_profile_pic_url_info][url]**

Thats it! :)

**[EDIT]**

If step **1** doesn't work,  my Php solution to get the **user-id**:

```
$name = "{username}";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.instagram.com/$name/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$http = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if($http=="200") {
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($result);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
  $js = $xpath->query('//body/script[@type="text/javascript"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $start = strpos($js, '{');
  $end = strrpos($js, ';');
  $json = substr($js, $start, $end - $start);
  $data = json_decode($json, true);
  $user_id = $data["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]["graphql"]["user"]["id"];
}
```

I'm searching in the HTML document for user-id.

Comment: That works. Curious - how did you figure this out? Especially the second part.

Comment: I thought that the 2. API requires an "access_token" but it's not the case. A user on GitHub told me that. However, I've spent a lot of time figure that out.

Comment: It looks like Instagram has changed something again and step 1 gets access denied...

Comment: @xC0dex yeah I used it in a online php compiler and I get this "Call to undefined function curl_init()"

Comment: @xC0dex And please add the `"}"` in the end for the `if`, for people who want to copy this out

Comment: @xC0dex your welcome, but it's better to use that vote up for comments ;)

Comment: In the profile page source HTML you can search for `logging_page_id`, it will followed by `profilePage_` and then a number. That number is the user ID. (migrated from [bax's "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49897190/1385678))

Comment: The second step doesn't seem to work anymore (since 2-3 days ago). Any other alternative?  :)

Comment: Now step 2 returns ``{"message":"useragent mismatch","status":"fail"}``

Answer (score 1):

If you view the source html and run a simple find text search for `logging_page_id`, it will have `profilePage_`, then a number. That number is the user id.

e.g.:

```
logging_page_id":"profilePage_123456789
```

The user id is: 123456789

Comment: Hi @bax. Thanks for your contribution! Since this isn't an answer to the OP question, this would better be a comment on another answer.