# Instagram ?__a=1 not working anymore

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I've been using Instagram's undocumented API `https://www.instagram.com/<user>/?__a=1` to get a public user feed on a website. Since a while now, this is not working anymore, probably because Facebook removed it. Is there an other way to get the data of an instagram account in a easy way?

Comment: Instagram blocked __a=1 endpoint , checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265339/instagram-a-1-url-doesnt-allow-max-id/49812302

Comment: Same solution with Php I updated my answer yesterday.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458818/instagram-pb-full-res/49479992#49479992

Comment: Too bad it's blocked completely... It's public available info for god's sake... But I already knew that was going to be the case, it was just a matter of time since Facebook acquired Instagram... And I know it's blocked, I'm just wondering if anyone knows a solid alternative solution.

Comment: @OlivierVanBulck I am facing the same problem. Would you please give instagram example with pagination?

Comment: @purvik7373 too bad I didn't find a solution with pagination yet

Comment: "?__a=1" seems to be working just fine.

Comment: It seems to work again indeed. Maybe they added it again because of complaints.

Comment: Whoa @OlivierVanBulck you're correct

Comment: like Instagram, any API for Pinterest.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I built a small server which does that transformation. You'll receive the instagram data as before with *?__a=1* (as JSON ) - have fun

```
https://www.instapi.io/u/<username>
```

https://www.instapi.io/u/appwithus

**EDIT 12/2020**: Unfortunately the service is no longer available

Comment: Do the cursors work? I did it with a GET variable called max_id and gave that one the next cursor but that's not working here right now?

Comment: Thats not possible, you can just provide your username, no additional parameters

Comment: Too bad it's not an option then, because that same logic I already had with stripping the HTML :/

Comment: I really need to load the rest of the posts

Comment: I'm trying to use your solution because there's not a better alternative, but I can't because there is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Can you add that?

Comment: @OlivierVanBulck I added it, it'll be online in a few minutes

Comment: @chrisby what's your secret? how are you fetching the data?

Comment: @chrisby Hell Yeah! Great work ! Thanks a alot but it's bit slower. And one question dude, do you know the 1080p profilepic getting trick ? And how to use the `?__a=1` with accesstoken ?

Comment: Would you like to share your source code (e.g. github)?

Comment: @wiesson, he is getting data with the help of web scrapper. you can see my answer below to get that code.

Comment: @ArbazAbid, I believe the same thing as chrisby does, using CURL, you can create your in own server with PHP or other server script and use GET method to get username value

Comment: instapi.io seems to have gone out of existence 

Comment: @DavidBaker I just found out the same. Too bad, I hope to find an alternative for simply fetching a set of pictures for a given account

Comment: Can you drop the code you used for instapi? It was very cool, I can pay for it

Answer (score 8):

Edit 15/03 **NOT WORKING ANYMORE** Seems like instagram changed again their API, now it gives a CORS error.

As of 2 february 2021, I have found a solution

Instead of using https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1 which it asks for a login.

Justing adding a /channel seems to make it work, like so:

https://www.instagram.com/username/channel/?__a=1

Comment: The original url without /channel gives the same result now I believe?

Comment: It does, but without /channel it sends a login page instead of the JSON in a GET request

Comment: How do you get the data? I've tried with   `resp.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges`and I get the following: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'graphql' of undefined at index.js:8`

Comment: data getting in postman using https://www.instagram.com/username/channel/?__a=1 url but not getting in react.Js project while calling api using fetch().

Comment: only thing i'm getting with postman is login page

Answer (score 4):

There is a JSON data in `https://www.instagram.com/<user>/`.
You can use regexp to find what you need.

Sample

```js
// This regexp gets widest possible dict around "profile_pic_url"
// but inside tag <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
let r = new RegExp('<script type="text\/javascript">' + 
                   '([^{]+?({.*profile_pic_url.*})[^}]+?)' +
                   '<\/script>');

let source = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
let jsonStr = source.match(r)[2];
let data = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
console.log('data', data);

let oldVariantOfData = data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0];
console.log('oldVariantOfData', oldVariantOfData);
```

Comment: Great option! Though it's not working perfectly for me. I need the info about the posts from that user. The json has the first 12 and a next cursor, but for what I know, there is no endpoint that I can use the next cursor on now. It seems the page is ignoring the information for pagination. Is there a way to get the rest of the posts in a new call?

Comment: any idea how to get next page?

Comment: In order to get 12 posts I use SlimerJS. First I got 12 posts, and read next cursor. Then I simulate scroll down action and capture respons with json, which url contains this cursor.I get new 12 posts from it and next cursor. etc.

Answer (score 2):

The same response is attached in the html response of the profile url, I perform this temporal solution (when I can't use the API) in python:

```
url_recent_media = 'https://www.instagram.com/%s/' % instagram_id
response = urllib2.urlopen(url_recent_media)

insta_html = response.read()
insta_html_split = insta_html.split('"ProfilePage":[')
if len(insta_html_split) > 1:
    insta_html_split_2 = insta_html_split[1].split(']},"gatekeepers"')
    if len(insta_html_split_2) > 1:
        json_dict = json.loads(insta_html_split_2[0])
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: It'd probably help, but too bad it's nothing more than a temporary solution. Whenever the code change, it won't work anymore... And Facebook will probably change it fast enough...

Answer (score 1):

you can try without using instagram API.

```
import json, urllib2

img_dicts = []
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/{}/'.format(instagram_username)
try:
    r = urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=10.0)
    instagram_html = r.read()
    instagram_html_data = instagram_html.split('"ProfilePage":[')
    if len(instagram_html_data) > 1:
        instagram_html_final_data = instagram_html_data[1].split(']},"gatekeepers"')
        if len(instagram_html_final_data) > 1:
            json_dict = json.loads(instagram_html_final_data[0])
            media = json_dict['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges']
            for obj in media:
                img_dicts.append({
                    'id': obj['node']['id'],
                    'caption': obj['node']['edge_media_to_caption']['edges'][0]['node']['text'],
                    'imgurl_standard': obj['node']['display_url'],
                    'imgurl_lower': obj['node']['thumbnail_resources'][4]['src'],
                    'imgurl_thumb': obj['node']['thumbnail_resources'][3]['src']
                })
```

`img_dicts` will give you images in different quality and caption of instagram post.