# Instagram api - endpoint for getting user_id by username has been retired

Tags: api, instagram, endpoint

The api end point bellow, for getting user_id by username has been retired in recent updates of instagam:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q={username}&access_token=

Is there another way to get those information by username?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use this link to parse the user-id

```
https://apinsta.herokuapp.com/u/USERNAME
```

This will give the `Json` data of user profile.
This is simply same as the old `?__a=1` but with limitations. But you can easily parse the user-id from this.

See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49862390/9749184