# Instagram /?__a=1 access denied

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

My question is regarding the new Instagram update, with the new Instagram update i can no longer access a public page JSON format via 
     https://www.instagram.com/nasa/?__a=1. I am using

```
`AsyncHttpClient client;
 client.get("https://www.instagram.com/nasa/?__a=1", 
 newTextHttpResponseHandler()`
```

I am using Android studio, any suggestions on how to proceed, i am getting the 
Access to www.instagram.com was denied

Comment: "?__a=1" seems to be working just fine.

Answer (score 3):

This was one of the undocumented endpoints it has to be stopped at some point because it was not supposed to be accessible to public. 
It is really recommend to not to use these undocumented endpoints in your app instead use Instagram API.

***Update 13th April***

You can get **USER_ID** using this php solution, I haven't tested it but you can try :-

```
$name = "{username}";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.instagram.com/$name/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$http = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if($http=="200") {
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($result);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
  $js = $xpath->query('//body/script[@type="text/javascript"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $start = strpos($js, '{');
  $end = strrpos($js, ';');
  $json = substr($js, $start, $end - $start);
  $data = json_decode($json, true);
  $user_id = $data["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]["graphql"]["user"]["id"];
}
```

Original Post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49479992/9565955

Comment: okay, thanks, looked a little more into it, how do i retrieve the id? i used to go on chrome window_shared data to get the id but that no longer works, i have a client id but thats not it

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/developer it is the better place to interact with as you will get all info about API endpoints and other basics.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue occur as well - it was a simple javascript implementation with a ajax request and then parsing the JSON. I needed a solution for my own website without wanting to go in and deal with their developer implementation and authentication for what was one profile.

I went looking for alternative ways to retrieve the data, starting requesting the entire main page, parsing the html into jquery and iterating through it that way. While doing so I found there's a script on the page which is near identical to what you would get with the `?__a=1` request:

`<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = ...`

I simply stripped the `window._sharedData =` portion of the script, as well as the trailing semi-colon, parsed that like you would with the `?__a=1` request, and used the data the same way - the actual post data is slightly more deeply nested but it's all there.