# How to download a full size Instagram profile picture via API

Tags: html, api, instagram, instagram-api, profile-picture

Does someone know how to download a fullsize instagram profile picture via the instagram api?

Answer (score -3):

[Instagram Profile Picture in Full-Resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458818/instagram-profile-picture-in-full-resolution)

Previously it worked as follows:

1.Get the user_id of the account using this link [https://www.instagram.com/{name}/?__a=1](https://www.instagram.com/%7Bname%7D/?__a=1)

2.Visit this JSON-API with the user_id above [https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/{user_id}/info/](https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/%7Buser_id%7D/info/) The full size profile picture link can be found in [hd_profile_pic_url_info][url]

but since 2-3 days ago The second step [hd_profile_pic_url_info][url] not available.Any other alternative? 
I'm having problem,finding no solution